# What Is The Authenticity Of This Narration About Jews In Ibn Ishaq's biography?

Tags: authenticity, seerah

I want to know about the authenticity of the following narration in Ibn Ishaq's biography:-

> When God wished to display His religion openly and to glorify His
> prophet and to fulfil His promise to him, the time came when he met a
> number of the Helpers at one of the fairs; and while he was offering
> himself to the Arab tribes as was his wont he met at al-'Aqaba a
> number of the Khazraj whom God intended to benefit. 'Asim b. 'Umar b.
> Qatada told me on the authority of some of the shaykhs of his tribe
> that they said that when the apostle met them he learned by inquiry
> that they were of the Khazraj and allies of the Jews. He invited them
> to sit with him and expounded to them Islam and recited the Quran to
> them. Now God had prepared the way for Islam in that they lived side
> by side with the Jews who were people of the scriptures and knowledge,
> while they themselves were polytheists and idolaters. They had raided
> them in their district and whenever bad feeling arose the Jews used to
> say to them, ‘A prophet will be sent soon. His day is at hand. We
> shall follow him and kill you by his aid as 'Ad and Iram perished.’ So
> when they heard the apostle's message they said one to another: ‘This
> is the very prophet of whom the Jews warned us. Don't let them get to
> him before us!’ Thereupon they accepted his teaching and became
> Muslims, saying, ‘We have left our people, for no tribe is so divided
> by hatred and rancour as they. Perhaps God will unite them through
> you. So let us go to them and invite them to this religion of yours;
> and if God unites them in it, then no man will be mightier than you’.
> Thus saying they returned to Medina as believers. ... When they came
> to Medina they told their people about the apostle and invited them to
> accept Islam until it became so well known among them that there was
> no home belonging to the Helpers but Islam and the apostle had been
> mentioned therein. (Ibn Ishaq's Sirat Rasul Allah, page no. 197-198)

**What is the authenticity of this narration in Ibn Ishaq?**

Comment: Could you be more specific? The narration is on the authority of 'Asim ibn 'Umar ibn Qatada a grandson of one of the Khazraj who met the prophet in the second pledge of al-'Aqabah.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - As stated in the question, my real concern is about the authenticity and the chain of narrators of this narration.

Comment: The chain of narrators might have an issue as some of the sheiks is not necessary acceptable however 'Asim is regarded as trustworthy as for the narration itself I don't know of any authentication or qualification on seerah books.